# How to restart Azure Web App programmatically

Tags: c#, azure, kudu

Is any way to restart the Azure Web App programmatically, i.e. Kudu or some another kind?

I'v found that it is possible using Management Libraries, but it is not applicable for me since I can't create application in AD.

Comment: [Power shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.websites/v2.7.0/restart-azurermwebapp) works great!

Answer (score 12):

Powershell:

```
Restart-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName xxx -Name xxx
```

or using the provider operation:

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName xxx -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/sites' -ResourceName xxx `
  -ApiVersion '2015-08-01' -Action 'Restart' -Force
```

Azure Cli (nodejs, depreciated):

```
azure webapp restart --resource-group xxx --name xxx
```

Azure Cli (python):

```
az appservice web restart --resource-group xxx --name xxx
```

or you can use [Rest Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps#WebApps_Restart)

Comment: See also [this](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/bf195e051935a6db3db196c63d9e8a124fc12aa9/ManagementLibrarySample/Program.cs#L295) for an example using the .NET library.

Comment: Hi David! Thank You, I saw You blog already and I have a question: can I do it without creating of AD Application? I already have Web App.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're looking for this feature because you or folks on your team don't have elevated permissions on the Azure Portal.

Creating scripts will work, but it still requires someone to be comfortable with running command lines.

The best way I found to do this is with VSTS pipeline. A few clicks and it's restarted. A simple and awesome way to build a devops culture.

[image]

Comment: Looked up VSTS to find "Visual Studio Team Services," with no hint how that (or the "Service Manage" image) is at all responsive to the question. If one is at the Azure portal, ONE click "and it's restarted," but that that doesn't help with programming a restart.

Comment: without knowing more about the reasons why you're doing this, i'm having reservations on why you're trying to do this. hence, i answered your questions from how your operational team at your company may want to do this when there is a prod issue.you may have to rethink your problem/solution. generally, programming a restart is a bad idea. in fact, IIS already does this for you with a recycle every 29 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer, which uses a LogicApp to make it a nice lightweight way to restart your web-app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59633629/44815