# How to automatically restart an app service after certain time?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

How to automatically restart an app service after 24 hours? How to schedule the app service to restart automatically at a specific time through the use of web jobs?

Answer (score 1):

We also could do that with [Azure Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps#WebApps_Restart). About how to get access token please refer to [azure document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#use-the-access-token-to-access-the-resource).

```
POST /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/restart?api-version=2016-08-01&softRestart&synchronous={softRestart&synchronous}
```

The following file types are accepted by [WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs#CreateScheduled):

> .cmd, .bat, .exe (using windows cmd)
>
> .ps1 (using powershell)
>
> .sh (using bash)
>
> .php (using php)
>
> .py (using python)
>
> .js (using node)
>
> .jar (using java)

If C# is possible, there is a [example](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/bf195e051935a6db3db196c63d9e8a124fc12aa9/ManagementLibrarySample/Program.cs#L295) using .Net library.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using LogicApps or RunBooks. Here is an example that uses Logic Apps: https://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2020/01/restarting-web-app-using-logic-apps.html

Basically, you create a trigger, and then you add a "Azure RM Invoke Action". The settings needed arent well documented, so I documented it in my blog post. This is basically the simplest way to make sure it happens on a schedule and brings together what has been previously discussed with regards to the REST API (the Azure RM action is using it under the covers), web-job (dont need to create one, as LogicApp will run it for you).

Answer (score -1):

Save-AzureRmProfile -Path "E:\azureprofile.json" returns an error but the command Save-AzureRmContext-Path "C:\script.json" gives the same output as that of of the Save-AzureRmProfile -Path "E:\azureprofile.json".

Comment: Please include the updates in the original question instand of posting an  answer that will make communities confused.